# strange compilation error with maven 'actual and formal parameters differ in length'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a class with default constructor and parameterized constructor as below,

```
public class Input {
    private String max;
    public Input() {

    }

    public Input(Input sourceInput) {
        this();
        this.max = sourceInput.getMax();
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "max")
    public String getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(String max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

I am instantiating the Input like below,

```
Input original = new Input();
original.setMax("20");
Input copy = new Input(original);
```

This code compiles well in eclipse. But when i compile this code using Maven, Maven Compiler plugin giving me below error for `Input copy = new Input(original);`

`constructor Input in class Input cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: ipm.calc.bridge.api.xsd.definition.Input
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code ?
Second constructor is created to obtain a copy of same object.
I have configures Java 8 for eclipse and Maven both. (here Maven means not eclipse integrated I have installed outside eclipse)

Comment: in the second snippet what is the object `input`?

Comment: sorry it was a typo.. i have edited the question please check now..

Comment: First do a **maven clean** to remove obsolete .class files. Then **maven package** or **install** should do.  This assumes the package path is okay, and the compilation is done in the same module, _not_ via the local repository on an older version, but versioned with SNAPSHOT, so actually the same version number.

Comment: anyway there is no need for that empty constructor `Input()`, also no need to call `this()` in the custom constructor.

Comment: @aSlug, this() always refers to default constructor. i.e `Input()` is required. i know it's a strange code my teammate has done this but it's risky refactor this beacuse it used at many places..

Answer (score 1):

```
Input original = new Input();
original.setMin("10");
original.setMax("20");
Input copy = new Input(input);
```

Where is the input in new Input(input). You should pass original instead of passing input to the constructor.It should be as follows

```
Input copy = new Input(original);
```

Comment: it was a typo in my question.. i have passed `original` object only.. then i got the error i mentioned in the question..